# Is it correct to say "It is the only way you see things that you have no idea occurred."?

Tags: sentence-structure

Is it correct to say " It is the only way to see things that you have no idea occurred."?

I guess there is supposed to be a preposition ‘about‘ or ‘of' after '**you have no Idea**', which I think is a attributive clause.

The material I read seems to be written by a native speaker of English, so I guess there might be some grammar rules that I don't know.